The ArrayList of select from MySQL DB which is returned isn't shown in JSP table
I've an method to select records in an mysql table this method are work fine but when I'll load the returned records in my jsp table the records is not showed in the table.
My JSP code:
<table class="tabela" id="tabpacientes">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <tr id="linha">
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 50px">Hora</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 175px">Nome</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 34px">Sexo</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 70px">Data</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 70px">Telefone</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tcorpo">                        
                <%
                    PacientesDAO_W01 pcdaopsqz = new PacientesDAO_W01();
                
                    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
                    String cnpj = session.getAttribute("cnpj").toString();
                    System.out.println("Pegando cnpj setado: " + cnpj);

                ArrayList<PesquisaExamesDia> pacientes = new ArrayList<PesquisaExamesDia>();
             
                    String CNPJ = session.getAttribute("cnpj").toString();
                    String dtaExames = "18/10/2024";
                    logger.info("pstm data ultra. recebido: " + dtaExames);

                    pacientes = pcdaopsqz.getPesquisaExamesDia(cnpj, dtaExames);
                    logger.info("Tabela retornada para JSP: " + pacientes);
                    request.setAttribute("pacientes", pacientes);
                %>
                    <c:forEach var="tabpacientes" items="${pacientes}">
                        <tr id="linha">
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 50px;"><c:out value="${tabpacientes.horaexame}"></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 175px;"><c:out value="${tabpacientes.nome}"></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 34px;"><c:out value="${tabpacientes.sexo}"></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 70px;"><c:out value="${tabpacientes.dataexame()}"></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 90px;"><c:out value="${tabpacientes.celular()}"></c:out></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>            
                </tbody>
            </table>

This cod below is the "view frame source" result executed in my browser.
<table class="tabela" id="tabpacientes">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <tr id="linha">
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 50px">Hora</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 175px">Nome</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 34px">Sexo</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 70px">Data</th>
                        <th id="lcabeca" style="width: 70px">Telefone</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tcorpo">                        
                
                    <c:forEach var="tabpacientes" items="[PesquisaExamesDia{cnpj=null, nome=Daniele dos Santos, prontuario=null, sexo=F, dataexame=18/10/2024, celular=(99)99999-9999, horaexame=10:00:00}, PesquisaExamesDia{cnpj=null, nome=Juscylene da Silva, prontuario=null, sexo=F, dataexame=18/10/2024, celular=(99)99999-9999, horaexame=08:30:00}]">
                        <tr id="linha">
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 50px;"><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 175px;"><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 34px;"><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 70px;"><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
                            <td id="lcoluna" style="width: 90px;"><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>            
                </tbody>
            </table>

As you can see the items var of forEach tag has the result of select mysql db.
I don't have any idea how to solve this because I've other tables into expression language that work fine.

Seems like the jstl tags aren't managed for that jsp: are you sure you have set all the necessary tags in the headers of the page. such as <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>? Check this with the other pages you say are working correctly.

This Question needs a [MCVE].

Are you messing taglib definition on the JSP page? What version of JSP are you using? The latest version is using <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %> for JSTL core tags in JSP. You can learn more about it from this question.

I forgot to copy this tag when I copied the pieces of the jsp page that work. Sorry by my mistake.
Thanks by your assistance.

Question solved and closed.
